# How to change string in file, but saving the changes in another file, not orginal one?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a small problem. In my *original.txt* file I got some scheme with one variable `zmuser` to change. 
I'm using `sed` command to change my variable  'zmuser' to other string, which is also a variable.

```
sed -i -e s/zmuser/${user}/g original.txt
```

It changes the `zmuser` for my `$user` variable in *original.txt*.

How can I  make changes from the file *original.txt* but save it in another *.txt* file?

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
sed -e "s/zmuser/${user}/g" original.txt > another.txt
```

**How it works:**

If you omit the `-i` flag from your `sed` command, the output will be printed on `stdout`. The `> another.txt` construct redirects that output to *another.txt* file.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do

```
   sed -n -e "s/zmuser/${user}/g" -e "w another.txt" original.txt
```